# Django Queries for related models

Tags: django

I have these two models, product and comment.

```
class Product(VoteModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, null=False,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(class)s_listings")
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, default=get_id, unique=True, editable=False)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    product_description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    num_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The Comment Model

```
class Comment(VoteModel, models.Model):
        user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        created_at     =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(_('IP address'), unpack_ipv4=True, blank=True, null=True)
        rating = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1.0)
         # Content-object field
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                         verbose_name=_('content type'),
                                         related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s",
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        object_pk = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
        content_object = GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")
```

Then, I have a serializer, in which I am trying to get the rating for the comments to come out with an average rating for each Item

```
class ProductSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    product_rating = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "product_rating"
        ]
        
   def get_product_rating(self, obj):

        comments = Comment.objects.filter(object_pk=obj.pk, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))

        ....

        return {'rating': str(float("%.1f" % average)), 'views': views}
```

This seems to be creating duplicate queries

> comments = Comment.objects.filter(object_pk=obj.pk,
> content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))

How can I rewrite the query better to avoid duplicate queries?
Here is the view, a little long:

```
class ProductsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    model = Product

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey | AllowAny]
    search_fields = ['product_title', 'product_description',
                     'user__first_name', 'product_type', 'product_price', 'product_city']
    pagination_class = ProductPageNumberPagination
  ....
   queryset_list = Product.objects.active().filter(lookups).distinct(
            ) if query and len(query) > 0 else Product.objects.active()

        return queryset_list
```

Comment: Can you please share your related view(set)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the view, which contains some fields  like the 'coordinates'. The Product model contains these fields. I just didnt add all the fields in the model here...

Comment: Do you know that you can use aggregation functions? So the computation of the avg will be done by the database using SQL instead of python. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Good point @KryštofŘeháček, I will try that out!

Comment: @KryštofŘeháček  But my current setup, aggregate will lead to more hits, which is what am trying to avoid. ```print(obj.comments.aggregate(Avg('rating')))```